# Cannot Convert value of type "CLLocationCoordinates2D" to closure result type 'Void'

Tags: swift, core-location, return-type

In this swift code, I am trying to make the function convert an address to a string, and after it does so successfully, it should return the coordinate as a CLLocationCoordinate2D

The error, *Cannot Convert value of type "CLLocationCoordinates2D" to closure result type 'Void*',pops up here:

```
return location.coordinate
```

and to combat this, I put a return type of CLLocationCoordinate2D and I put a parameter of address, which is the user inputted string.

Here is the full code:

```
func getCoordinates(address: String) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to retrieve location")
            return
        }
        
        var location: CLLocation?
        
        if let placemarks = placemarks, placemarks.count > 0 {
            location = placemarks.first?.location
        }
        
        if let location = location {
            let coordinate = location.coordinate
            
            print("\nlat: \(coordinate.latitude), long: \(coordinate.longitude)")
            
            return location.coordinate
        }
        else
        {
            print("No Matching Location Found")
        }
    })
    
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time to help me solve this issue.